# Explain $du = g'(x) dx$ when $u=g(x)$

Tags: integration, derivatives

I have seen the following multiple times in the book Calculus by James Stewart.

For instance, it appears in the proof of the substitution rule (or change of variable) for integral.

Suppose $u = g(x)$ and $\dfrac{du}{dx} = g'(x)$.

Then, $du = g'(x) dx$.

$\dfrac{du}{dx}$ is the derivative of $u$ with respect to $x$ not it is definitely not a fraction.

For instance, the $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{dy}{dt}\times \dfrac{dt}{dx}$ holds true as proven as the Chain Rule.

So why does $du = g'(x) dx$ hold  true? And what does this mean?

I need a clear explanation on this concept please. Appreciate your help, thanks :)

Comment: It's possible to develop calculus rigorousIy without making statements like $df = f'(x) dx$.  This is done in real analysis textbooks such as Calculus by Spivak. Also, it is important to understand that if the input to a function $f$ changes from $x$ to $x+\Delta x$, and $\Delta f$ is the corresponding change in the value of $f$, then $\Delta f \approx f'(x) \Delta x$. The approximation is good when $\Delta x$ is small.  You can make sense of arguments involving $dx$ and $df$ by rephrasing them in terms of tiny but finite numbers $\Delta x$ and $\Delta f$ and replacing = with $\approx$.

Comment: how can $df$ be replaced by $\Delta f$? If so, you saying that $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ is $\dfrac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}.$ And obviously its not, because $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ is a function.

Comment: I suggest you google differentials and non standard analysis.

Comment: @LittleRookie  A key part of my comment was that = should be replaced with $\approx$. So,  $y'(x) \approx \Delta y/\Delta x$. I was using the phrase "make sense of" a little loosely. I don't mean that such arguments can be made rigorous in the manner I described. I just meant that arguments involving $df$ and $dx$ contain valuable intuition. If you want perfectly rigorous arguments, they can be found in real analysis textbooks.

Comment: @ty. "I suggest you google ... non standard analysis" Sorry but, do you *hate* the guy? Seeing the extremely basic level of their confusion, to send them to NSA...

Comment: @Did Leibniz notation and non standard analysis go well together. Non standard analysis to me is much easier to understand.

Comment: @ty. Ha. Did you ever teach basic analysis to standard (pun intended) first year students?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Leibniz notation does **not** denote a fraction, as you know, so it is not technically correct to treat it as one and 'separate' the top and bottom. Also, given $u = g(x)$ we never need to say things like $du = g'(x) dx$. After all, simple analysis suffices to get what you actually want, in this case the change of variable theorem.
$
\def\lfrac#1#2{{\large\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$

---

Take any differentiable function $g : D \to U$, and any real/complex parameter $x$ varying in $D$.

Let $u = g(x)$. Then $\lfrac{du}{dx} = g'(x)$.

Take any continuous function $f$ on $U$. Then $\int f(u)\ du$ exists (on the path traced by $x$).

Thus $\lfrac{d(\int f(u)\ du)}{dx} = \lfrac{d(\int f(u)\ du)}{du}·\lfrac{du}{dx} = f(u)\lfrac{du}{dx}$, by chain rule and definition of anti-derivative.

Thus $\int f(u)\ du = \int f(u) \lfrac{du}{dx}\ dx + k$ for some constant $k$. Note that here we are using a basic theorem that if $\lfrac{dy}{dx} = z$ everywhere (on the path traced by $x$) then $y = \int z\ dx + k$ for some constant $k$.

You can see that nowhere do we break apart the derivative notation.

---

To look at the little bits, recall that as $Δx \to 0$ we have $\lfrac{Δu}{Δx} \approx g'(x)$, which implies **much more** than $Δu \approx g'(x)·Δx$. It in fact implies that $Δu - g'(x)·Δx \ll Δx$.

Intuitively, as $x$ changes by $Δx$, $u$ will change by $Δu$, and the change in $\int f(u)\ du$ divided by $Δu$ is approximately $f(u)$. Hence $Δ(\int f(u)\ du)$ divided by $Δx$ is approximately $f(u)·\lfrac{Δu}{Δx}$. If you add up the little bits over the entire path of $x$, then the total change of $\int f(u)\ du$ is approximately the sum of $f(u)·\lfrac{Δu}{Δx}$ over all the little changes in $x$.

Comment: I'm for the change of variable theorem. The author James Stewart uses this notation $du = g'(x) dx$ many times in the sections that involve integration. Perhaps it is a shorthand notation for something. I will look at it again.

Comment: @LittleRookie: I take it as just a mnemonic (memory device); it is not rigorous and you will not see rigorous textbooks (such as Spivak's) do that. It is perfectly ok to use intuitive mnemonics to help, and even to guess what might be true, but a rigorous proof must always be found. There is something called differentials as linear maps, but I **very very strongly** recommend not even looking that up until you have a solid grasp of real analysis including rigorous proofs of the basic theorems such as the change of variable theorem. =)

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it technically doesn't mean anything. Splitting the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ symbol is just a convenient way of remembering rules like the chain rule and the rule for changing variable in integration.

Comment: i did not mention that it has no meaning. I said $du = g'(x) dx$ holds true, but it should not be seen as a fraction.

Answer (score -2):

When you are working with differentials you actually zoom so close to point on the curve that the curve behaves as a straight line.

[image]

Coefficient of the line is derivative of $g(x)$ in that point.

So yes, it is actually a fraction.

Comment: You see $du$ and $dx$ as some quantity. But im not referring to that.

Comment: Most curves *never* become a straight line.

Comment: @LittleRookie $du$ and $dx$ are super small quantities and they are bounded to each other as presented on the image. I don't know what your referring to anyway...

Comment: This is good intuition, but no matter how much you zoom in, the curve will never be perfectly straight. So if the goal is to be rigorous, this explanation isn't satisfactory.

Comment: @Henrik of course they don't, it is approximately a line. But it looks like and you do calculations as it was a line

Comment: Then you should not use the word "becomes". because it will never be equal to the line. Such bad phrasing may mislead people.

Comment: @littleO to be rigorous, you zoom it to the level where curvature is negligible to the length of differentials

Comment: @LittleRookie I changed "becomes" to "behaves as"